# window.location.reload(false) migration from Typescript 3 to typescript 4

Tags: typescript

I have a web application with this instruction: `window.location.reload(false)`and I 'm using typescript version 3. Now I have to migrate from typescript 3 to 4, but I have a problem on this method `window.location.reload(false)`.

```
Expected 0 arguments, but got 1.  TS2554

    108 |         onClick={async () => {
    109 |           await AppStore.setLanguage('it')
  > 110 |           window.location.reload(false)
        |                                  ^
    111 |         }}
    112 |       >
```

I can migrate it?

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to use a variant of `reload` that's only supported by Firefox. This means that TS will complain about sending a param to a method that shouldn't have one.

One way of getting away with it is to do a cast to a function that expects one boolean parameter. Something similar to this:

`(window.location.reload as (cache: boolean) => void)(false)`